# Are there windows that create asymmetric sidelobes

Tags: fft, dft, window-functions

I am working on a project which uses radar imaging. The radar imaging takes place at a relatively small distance from the radar (0.25m to 3m). The data is collected using an FMCW radar. The FFT of the collected data is taken to calculate the target range. I want to reduce the sidelobes of the calculated range asymmetrically. Specifically, I want the sidelobes at a larger range than the target to have a smaller magnitude than those at a smaller range than the target.

The reason I want to do this is that for a given target, the power received should decrease as $ r^4 $ per the radar equation. The $ r^4 $ factor can be taken to imply that for the same target, my response will decrease -12 dB every time I double my distance from the radar.

This means that if I have a target at 0.25m and 2m of the same size then I would expect the target at 2m to be -36 dB down from the target at 0.25m. In order to push the sidelobes down below -36 dB, I would need to use a pretty aggressive window, and even then, the -36 dB will make it difficult to see targets that are far away and small. i.e., at large ranges, there is likely to be a small dynamic range before my targets have the same magnitude as the side lobe level.

Thank You,

Comment: The Fourier Transform of any **real** function of time, has Hermitian symmetry in the frequency domain.  The magnitude is even symmetry and the phase is odd symmetry.   But you could define a main lobe with asymmetric sidelobes and inverse Fourier Transform back to the time domain, and you will get a window function that has complex values.

Comment: This can copy-paste as an answer, OP should create another question about the specific design @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes please paste that as the answer, I think it is sufficient and generally helpful

Comment: If you don't I will!

Comment: I assume that you have full control over the waveform being transmitted and also you are not doing traditional FMCW processing at the receiver. For your problem try non-linear FMCW waveforms as given in the following paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/10/21/3939/pdf

Comment: oh, all right.  <sheesh>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fourier Transform of any **real** function of time, has Hermitian symmetry in the frequency domain. The magnitude is even symmetry and the phase is odd symmetry. But you could define a main lobe with asymmetric sidelobes and inverse Fourier Transform back to the time domain, and you will get a window function that has complex values.